# .htaccess returns 500 but gets fixed when re-arranging the rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Some weird stuff happening in .htaccess file

File that does not works

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*?)/([a-z0-9_-]+)$ $1/post?id=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/edit/([a-z0-9_-]+)$ $1/editpost.php?id=$2 [L,QSA]

#RewriteRule ^users/(\d+)*$ ./profile.php?id=$1
```

But this works

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*?)/edit/([a-z0-9_-]+)$ $1/editpost.php?id=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/([a-z0-9_-]+)$ $1/post?id=$2 [L,QSA]

#RewriteRule ^users/(\d+)*$ ./profile.php?id=$1
```

I simply re-arranged the rewrite rule and it fixed the issue. Can anyone explain why this happened? I was stuck in this for more than 2 hrs.

I am new to URL rewriting so please explain in detail. And what actually [L, QSA] does?

Comment: For your second question, look at [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteCond` is only applicable to nearest `RewriteRule`. So in your first example it is applied to only this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/([a-z0-9_-]+)$ $1/post?id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Two bottom `RewriteRule` are executed without any `RewriteCond` and cause infinite loop.

You can have your rules as:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# skip all files and directories from rules below    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*?)/edit/([\w-]+)/?$ $1/editpost.php?id=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^users/(\d+)/?$ profile.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.*?)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1/post?id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: No the new code is giving me 404 error..but the infinite loop is not happening now. 404 even when i use the old ugly url.

Comment: Wait as soon as I remove the 1 line from ur code everything is normal now...can u explain why?

Comment: Options -MultiViews

Comment: ok. Option `MultiViews` (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html) is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So if `/file` is the URL then Apache will serve `/file.html`.

Comment: Most likely your target `post?id=...` executing `post.php?id=...`

Comment: Oh I understood this concept now. Thanks sir for helping me out.